What parts of Michael Moorcock’s books do you see in “Warhammer 40,000”?
I have heard that Rick Priestley, the creator of the “Warhammer” miniature wargame, cites J.R.R. Tolkien, H.P. Lovecraft, “Dune”, “Paradise Lost” and “2000 AD” as major influences of the setting for “Warhammer 40,000”?
However, I have also heard that Michael Moorcock’s books might have been another influence.
I have read Moorcock’s “The History of the Runestaff” series. Well, okay, I have read the “Hawkmoon” comics published by First Comics, but it gives me an idea of the contents.
The part of the series that I can easily compare to “Warhammer 40,000” is King-Emperor Huon (KEH). I would not be surprised if KEH served as a template for the Emperor of Mankind (EOM).
In fact, I should list the similarities and differences between the two characters.
Similarities

Both KEH and EOM are immortal.
Both KEH and EOM rule powerful, expansionist empires.
Both KEH and EOM are considered gods by the citizens of their empires.
Both KEH and EOM were handsome at one time, but have become hideous creatures.
Both KEH and EOM have families.
Both KEH and EOM are on life support.
Both KEH and EOM are betrayed by a high-ranking warrior with a wolf theme.
Both KEH and EOM fight a civil against the aforementioned traitor with a wolf theme.
Both KEH and EOM are powered by a forsaken child.
Both KEH and EOM have grand ambitions.

Differences

KEH is 2,000 years old, whereas EOM is 48,000 years old.
KEH’s Dark Empire of Granbretan (Great Britain, ha ha) has conquered most of Europe, expects to conquer all Arabia, and is trying to muster the resources to attack Asiacommunista. In contrast to this, EOM’s Imperium of Man spans across the galaxy with at least one million worlds under its banner…until the Great Rift’s eruption practically cuts the Imperium of Man in half.
KEH encourages his subjects to worship him as a god to the point that “By Huon!” is a common phrase. In contrast, EOM did everything he could to discourage his subjects from worshipping him, but after the events of the Horus Heresy, they just worship him as a god even more than before.
KEH probably used to be handsome, but now he looks like a deformed fetus with an enlarged head. In contrast to this, EOM started out as a giant handsome man in golden armour (or at least a man with an ordinary appearance), but now he looks like a shrivelled, mummified skeleton.
KEH’s only living relative is Countess Flana Mikosevaar, his cousin, whereas EOM started out with a family and eventually created 20 clone-sons named the Primarchs (that suffered heavy losses).
KEH has to stay inside a Throne-Globe filled with amniotic fluid to stay alive. In contrast, EOM, mortally wounded, has to sit on the Golden Throne to preserve his life (but there are signs in recent stories that he is coming back).
KEH is betrayed by Baron Meliadus of Kroiden, a high-ranking general who wears a wolf mask. In contrast to this, EOM is betrayed by Horus Lupercal, his favourite clone-son, whose last name could be translated as “Wolf Festival.”
KEH fights a civil war against Meliadus, which ends with Meliadus killing KEH right in his throne room and taking over Granbretan. In contrast, EOM kills Horus, but he himself is mortally wounded and has to be hooked to the Golden Throne to preserve his life.
KEH has a young-sounding voice because it was stolen by an unfortunate youth and transferred to him, whereas EOM needs 1,000 psykers sacrificed a day to keep his Golden Throne going.
KEH’s ambition is to rule the entire world, whereas EOM’s ambition is to reduce humanity’s reliance on psykers and create a human dominion with science and reason as its driving force.

That was a lot to list, I know. So that is one part of Michael Moorcock’s books that I see in “Warhammer 40,000.” Does anyone else see other parts of Michael Moorcock’s books in “Warhammer 40,000,” and if so, what are they?

Chaos. https://stormbringer.fandom.com/wiki/Chaos

A lot of the visual style of Chaos (the eight-pointed star and the mutation of Chaos worshippers being the most notable) were lifted directly from Moorcock's work.
